# most recent release of xcode for leopard, not snow leopard

Tags: macos, gcc, osx-leopard

compiling an app that needs to be compiled with a newer version of the gcc than is available with xcode 3.0 (what is on disk for the leopard install) but the newest download link for 3.2.4 only runs on snow leopard.

what is the latest release of xcode that runs on leopard and if you have a link to the dmg that would be awesome. its torture to find anything on the apple dev center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3.1.4 is the last release, to my knowledge, that supports 10.5. It can be found on the old developer connection site; here's a direct link (may need to sign in first):

http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/xcode_3.1.4_developer_tools/xcode314_2809_developerdvd.dmg

Comment: thanks, i saw that list and didnt look close enough to find the xcode releases. I appreciate the help, and you're right as far as i can tell 3.1.4 is the last release for 10.5

Comment: Hi, one question, is it necessary to download all previous versions to install 3.1.4? I mean, 3.1, 3.1.1, etc...

Answer (score 1):

The Leopard version of Xcode 3.1.4 can be found third from the bottom on page 6 at https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action#